# Определённый интеграл методом трапеций и прямоугольников с заданной точностью

Tags: c++, математика, численные-методы

Всем доброго времени суток! Столкнулся со следующей проблемой при подсчете определенного интеграла функции f(x) = sin(x)*cos(x^2) на отрезке [a, b] и с заданной точностью.

Суть проблемы в том, что методом прямоугольников получаются не закономерные значения:

| Точность | Метод трапеций | Метод прямоугольников |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.01 | 0.100304 | 0.0791528 |
| 0.001 | 0.100341 | 0.100349 |
| 0.0001 | 0.100345 | 0.0982234 |

Правильный ответ в моем случае (по вольфраму) должен быть **0.100345**.

Для реализации методов я сначала находил количество отрезков разбиения *n* с помощью формул абсолютных погрешностей этих двух методов:

[image: Погрешность метода трапеций]

и

[image: погрешность метода прямоугольнков]

Ниже представлен код для поиска количества отрезков разбиения для методов трапеций (для метода прямоугольников код почти идентичный, за исключением коэффициента в знаменателе дроби при поиске погрешности)

```
int n = 1;
double max = fabs(sec_derivative(eps, a));
for (double i = a + eps; i <= b; i += eps) {
    if (max < fabs(sec_derivative(eps, i))) {
        max = fabs(sec_derivative(eps, i));
    }
}
double fault = max * pow((b - a), 3) /(12* pow(n, 2));
while (fault > eps) {
    n++;
    fault = max * pow((b - a), 3) / (12 * pow(n, 2));
}
double h = (b - a) / n;
```

Вторую производную брал следующим образом:

```
double sec_derivative(double eps, double x) {
    return (f(x + eps) - 2 * f(x) + f(x - eps)) / pow(eps, 2);
}
```

Далее находил, собственно, сам ответ:

```
double ans = 0; //метод прямоугольников
for (double i = a; i < b; i += h) {
    ans += f(i + (h / 2));
}
ans *= h;
return ans;
```

и

```
double ans = 0; //метод трапеций
for (double i = a + h; i < b - h; i += h) {
    ans += f(i);
}
ans *= 2;
ans += f(a) + f(b);
ans *= h / 2;
return ans;
```

Никак не могу понять, в чем моя ошибка(и есть ли она вообще?), поэтому подскажите, пожалуйста!

По ходу решения задачи возник вопрос из раздела математики: формулу для приближенного значения второй производной взял из интернета, но при собственном выводе получилось очень похоже, но в аргументе каждой функции получилось значение, большее на некое *Eps*, т.е. f(x + 2*eps) вместо f(x + eps) и т.д.

Понимаю, что разница выйдет не особо критичной, но в случае формулы, взятой из интернета ответ получается более точный, нежели с моей. Не понимаю, по какому принципу вывели эту формулу (просто вычли из каждого аргумента *Eps* и получили более правильный ответ?) и вообще, как вывести формулы для приближенных значечний производных бо́льших порядков (получилось вывести для производной 4-й степени, но в связи с вышеописанной проблемой не уверен, что получилось верно)

Comment: Верхняя граница в циклах проверяется не точно. Иногда последний отсчет включается в сумму, иногда нет. Переделайте циклы на ровно n итераций.

Comment: И еще - кроме первого совета. Вам вообще не надо тратить время на расчет этой второй производной - с таким-то шагом... Просто оцените сверху это значение на бумажке, если уж на то пошло. А еще точность можно оценить, пройдясь с некоторым шагом, и сравнив значения для, например, h и h/2. Кстати, а чему у вас равны a и b? я что-то не нашел...

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, последний отсчет включатся/не включается исходя из найденных формул для этих методов.

Comment: @harry, a = 0, b = 5

Comment: @hjbaa, вещественные числа складываются приближенно. Например, из-за этого приближения в методе прямоуголников вы иногда делаете лишнюю итерацию.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, спасибо, попробую переделать

Comment: Странно, что погрешность метода трапеций получается больше погрешности метода прямоугольников. Так не бывает :)

Answer (score 1):

И все же я бы решал путем удвоения количества отрезков...

```
double trapez(double(*f)(double), double a, double b, double eps)
{
    double old_i = 0, new_i = old_i+2*eps;
    for(unsigned int n = 1; abs(new_i-old_i) > eps; n *= 2)
    {
        old_i = new_i;
        double h = (b-a)/n, s = -(f(a) + f(b))/2;
        for(int i = 0; i <= n; ++i)
            s += f(a + i*h);
        new_i = s*h;
    }
    return new_i;
}

double y(double x) { return sin(x)*cos(x*x); }

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    cout << trapez(y,0,5,1e-6) << endl;
}
```

[Ответ](https://ideone.com/Xfguiq) — как у Wolfram'а :)